# React-Router—Add/remove Routes at runtime

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router, react-redux, react-router-redux

I have an Application which supports privileges for each user. So if the user has to appropriate permission, he is able to manage users, groups and so on. In case the User hasn't such permission he might not do that.

I have an rest api, with an endpoint, returning all the allowed links for the current user, and with that, I would like to setup the routes for the `react-router`. In case the permissions are edited and, for instance, the user looses the permission to edit users, the respective Menu Item should disappear from the menu and the route removed from the router. Otherwise a menu item and the route should be added.

Right now I have this setup:

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <Router history={history}>
      <Route path="/" component={Window}>
        <IndexRoute component={Users} />
        <Route path="users" component={Users} />
        <Route path="groups" component={Groups} />
        <Route path="permissions" component={Permissions} />
        <Route path="*" component={Error} />
      </Route>
    </Router>
  </Provider>, mount);
```

But I really would like to have is: A function which does this setup dynamically and can be run each time Permissions change.

I could not find any documentation about that and I would be glad if there is a way to do that.

**UPDATE**

According to the given answers and the comments, I realized that the way I wanted to tackle this problem does not go along with the declarative nature of react-router.

Comment: Why do you want to do this at runtime? Usually the permissions should be loaded for each user during login. That makes your life lot easier.

Comment: Because the user can change permissions, so he can loose the needed permissions for a distinct route. Blocking might be a solution, but removing the route appears cleaner for me. If this is not the right thought, let me know.

Comment: What do you expect by letting someone edit their own permissions. What is the business scenario? Can you force them to login after editing their permissions. That way you can send new routes from server without worrying about handling them in the client side.

Comment: I think one problem with dynamically adding/removing routes could be the maintainability of said routes when your app grows and you add more routes.  If you use `onEnter` and check the route against the list of authorised routes that's come from the API, it should be little effort when adding new routes in the future.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

in one of my project i have a following setup, i think you will find it usefull:

```
componentWillMount() {
  let routes = [];

  routes.push({
    path: '/authenticate',
    component: LoginPage
  });

routes.push({
  path: '/',
  component: Main,
  indexRoute: { component: null },
  getChildRoutes: (error, callback) => {
    getNavigation().then((nav) =>{
      callback(null, getChildRoutes(nav.paths))
    })
  },
  onEnter: () => {
    getNavigation();
    let token = getToken();
    if (token == null || token === '') redirectToAuthenticationUrl();
  }
});

this.routes = routes;

render() {
  return (
    <Router key={uuid()} history={history} routes={this.routes} />
  );
}
```

You can store your routes in an object, and also pass a promise that will return your routes, you can also check for permissions easily this way. Hope that helps!

Comment: I accepted this answer since it gave me more help. But in general both given answers pointed out to use the `onEnter` callback which is the weapon of choice for this problem.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `onEnter` prop on `Route` for conditional auth.  You can check whether a user has permission to enter the view, and if they don't, navigate them away elsewhere.

See: https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/docs/API.md#onenternextstate-replace-callback

```
<Route path='/accounts' component={Accounts} onEnter={isAuth} />

const isAuth = (nextState, replace) => {
  if (!isCurrentUserAuthorised) {
    replace({pathname: '/'});
  }
}
```

The `isAuth` method is entered when navigating to `/accounts`.  Obviously you'd need to put your own logic in for determining if the user is authorised, but that's the jist of it.  Just put a pathname of where you'd like unauthorised users to be sent away to.

Comment: I think the question is not only block users from accessing, the links should not be there too. In your solution it seems the user can still click the link.

Comment: The routing logic and UI logic are separate.  OP can still conditionally set the UI menu links based off what they got from their API, however if someone were to manually try and access an unauthorised link, they'll be redirected away.